# golang compile error: can't find import

Tags: go

I am trying to run `go build` command in a directory `$GOPATH/src/call/httptest`:

```
maks@myMac ~/Dropbox/golang/src/call/httptest $ go build
# call/httptest
./domain.go:4: can't find import: "call"
```

Have error `./domain.go:4: can't find import: "call"`

The beginning of `domain.go` file:

```
package httptest

import (
    "call" // line 4 - error is here
)
```

I can successfully build in `$GOPATH/src/call` directory:

```
maks@myMac ~/Dropbox/golang/src/call $ go build
```

**Why** can't I import `call` in `$GOPATH/src/call/httptest/domain.go` file although `call` is  in `$GOPATH/src` directory?

Gopath is the following:

```
$ echo $GOPATH
/Users/maks/Dropbox/golang

$ go version
go version go1.4.3 darwin/amd64
```

## Update

```
$ go env
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCHAR="6"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/maks/Dropbox/golang"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
CC="clang"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fno-common"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="0"
```

Comment: Please show full output of `go env`

Comment: @Volker added full output of `go env` above

Comment: I have not had success with source files off of `/src/call/foo.go`. I think the go tool may need an additional level of nesting.

Comment: Please provide a minimal example that reproduces the issue.  I just tried with two files `$GOPATH/src/foo/foo.go` which simply declares an exported constant `const Foo = 8`, and `$GOPATH/src/foo/bar/bar.go` which imports "foo" and sets a variable `var Bar = foo.Foo`.  Then from the `bar` directory I ran `go build` and did not see any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was kinda "cache" issue. After I change couple lines in `$GOPATH/src/call`, I become able to build in `$GOPATH/src/call/httptest` without that import error.

Comment: Same happened to me with some procedurally generated proto imports. This spared me from a huge headache!